# I cant get array value from my server responce

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp

I have my server respond me with an dictionary.
The console.log(responce) returns this:

```
{"filters":{
  "Facture": [
    "Магма (Тычок)",
    "Тонкий кирпич",
    "Гладкий",
    "Крафт",
    "Магма"
  ],
  "Color": [
    "Беж",
    "Черный",
    "Амстердам",
    "Лондон Брик",
    "Мюнхен",
    "Сити Брик"
  ],
  "Name": [
    "Облицованный кирпич стандартный пустотелый",
    "Тонкий колотый с ф. 180/11"
  ]
}}
```

But when i try to access the value with this code:

```
console.log(xhr.responseText);

const response = xhr.responseText;
console.log(response);

const myObj = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(myObj);

var names = myObj.Name.map(name => name.trim());
var types = myObj.Facture.map(type => type.trim());
var colors = myObj.Color.map(color => color.trim());

console.log(names);
console.log(types);
console.log(colors);
```

It returns undefined in the console. Please help me get the value....
The only clue that i got, that if i create this object inside of my script it works correct, but doesnt work when i get the object through the responce

I tried literally everything:
Changing the data i send by the server
Accessing the value with different code...

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
const myObj = JSON.parse(response);
```

to

```
const myObj = JSON.parse(response).filters;
```

since the values you look for seem to be inside the property *filters*.

#### Edited

See, comments - it turns out the server returned "{...}" rather than {...} so we hade to double parse it:

```
const myObj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response)).filters;
```

A better solution if you have control of the server/backend would be to fix this there.

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried console.log on myObj after that and it returns as undefined. But the server responce is correct, looks the same as in my question.
Maybe the full code will help:

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);

                const response = xhr.responseText;
                console.log(response);

                const myObj = JSON.parse(response).filters;
                console.log(myObj);

Comment: Exactly what do you get back from JSON.parse(response) - have you tried console.logging that?

Comment: I included that in my question - it's not a raw responce from the server, it's already edited by the json.parse()

Comment: Here it is again:
{"filters":{
  "Facture": [
    "Магма (Тычок)",
    "Тонкий кирпич",
    "Гладкий",
    "Крафт",
    "Магма"
  ],
  "Color": [
    "Беж",
    "Черный",
    "Амстердам",
    "Лондон Брик",
    "Мюнхен",
    "Сити Брик"
  ],
  "Name": [
    "Облицованный кирпич стандартный пустотелый",
    "Тонкий колотый с ф. 180/11"
  ]
}}

Comment: And it is an object. You can 'fold out' properties of it in your console? (Not a string I mean)

Comment: No i cant, it just shows like a string

Comment: If i log the raw responce from the server it looks like this and i can't do anything with it in the console aswell:
"{"filters":{\r\n  "Facture": [\r\n    "Магма (Тычок)",\r\n    "Тонкий кирпич",\r\n    "Гладкий",\r\n    "Крафт",\r\n    "Магма"\r\n  ],\r\n  "Color": [\r\n    "Беж",\r\n    "Черный",\r\n    "Амстердам",\r\n    "Лондон Брик",\r\n    "Мюнхен",\r\n    "Сити Брик"\r\n  ],\r\n  "Name": [\r\n    "Облицованный кирпич стандартный пустотелый",\r\n    "Тонкий колотый с ф. 180/11"\r\n  ]\r\n}}"

Comment: That is strange - the JSON.parse should make it an object. I must admit I haven't worked with old-school AJAX / XHR in year, I always use fetch instead but still...

Comment: Last resort - what happens if you double parse it JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response)).filters - just curious

Comment: Yeah, i have tried solving this problem for like a day and seem's like no one ever got this problem exept me :( But thank you a lot anyway, will try to remake my request with fetch, didn't worked with that but i guess it might be better...

Comment: After you asked for double parsing i questioned my existance in this world. It works now.... But why it needs to be double parsed?....

Comment: It seems like your server is returning it like this "{....}" not {} like it is supposed to so parsing once just gives you a string, parsing twice solves the problem. If you have control over the backend - change so it does not output "..." around the JSON

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check the backend code and fix that too!

Comment: "...something" is technically valid JSON but will just be parsed into a string...

Comment: Glad we solved it!